# Odd checkbox behavior in DataGridView with databinding

Tags: .net, datagridview

I am using databinding to bind List with my datagridview.

MyItem class contains checkbox element and displays correctly in datagridview. 
But the selection behavior is odd. When I select the check box the same field in MyItem does not update.

When I change selected row(focus on checkedbox lost) the same field in corresponding instance of MyItem class is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are describing is the standard behaviour for all DataGridView cell types - the [cell value changed event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) (and the databinding) occurs when focus leaves the cell.

As they say in the article I linked to, and as you allude to in your question, for a checkbox this behaviour is often not ideal. To work around this you can handle the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged`
and call the `CommitEdit` method. There is some discussion and example code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx).